# Can I pull data from Localytics API into google sheets?

Tags: google-apps, localytics

Using the script editor? How do I go about it? I'm not a coder but I work with data and would like to automate funnel data right into my google spreadsheet. Detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured it out but you can use Google Sheets to pull data from Localytics. You just need to reach out to Support @ Localytics.com requesting the sheet, and they can get a link sent out to you. They'll also provide the instructions on how to utilize it as well, so you're not confused.

Answer (score 1):

Ya, you can pull the data via the API provided by Localytics or the AWS dump provided by Localytics.

**API Method:**
You can write a python script with get requests in order to fetch the data from Localytics API. You can store the same in a Relational Database or populate in a csv file. Go ahead and explore the requests library in python which can help you get the required data. You can write the output in a csv file to open it in excel.

Localytics even provides daily dump to your AWS s3 bucket. For that, you need to get in touch with the Localytis customer care so that they can set up daily dumps for your app/web. You can fetch the data from S3 as csv files directly.